# visual c++ 2005 dll project and prerequisites needs to be installed on target machine

Tags: visual-c++, installation, distribution

i wrote a simple dll and i included below header files:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <sddl.h>
#include <winsock.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mprapi.h>
#include <raserror.h>
#include <mprerror.h>
#include <strsafe.h>
```

so my dll works fine in my computer but in another computer not working. i installed vcredist_x86 on target machine but nothing changed. i also used setup deploy wizard and nothing happend. but when i installed visual studio 2005 on target machine my dll works perfectly.

so here is the question, how can i retrieve which prerequisites needs to be installed on target machine?

also i must mention that i compiled my code as c code "Compile as C Code (/TC)".

sorry for my poor english and thanks for your helps in advance.

Comment: Are you building in relase or debug. I had a similar issue when I was trying to deploy a debug build.

Comment: i googled my problem before and i aware of the problem you mentioned but i tried both debug and release version and nothing changed.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your suggestion. even i tried release version before but it's ringed a bell. i checked my project properties, and setting for release wasn't the settings that i used for debug. after resetting project properties for release version and  compiled it, it's working fine. thank you.

Comment: Ok glad to here its working for you.